# Finding the maximum difference between columns from different rows

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Given the following data:

| Course_ID | Teacher_ID | Minimum_grade | Maximum_grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 7 |
| 4 | 3 | 5 | 8 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 | 7 |
| 6 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 4 | 4 | 6 |
| 8 | 4 | 5 | 7 |

using Postgresql, I need to write a query to:

> select all teachers who taught 2 **separate** courses X and Y where
> the difference between the minimum grade of course X and maximum grade
> of course Y is greater than 2.

Thus, only teacher 4 should be selected.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT Teacher_ID, MAX(Maximum_grade), MIN(Minimum_grade)
FROM dataset
GROUP BY Teacher_ID
HAVING count(Teacher_ID) > 1 AND (MAX(Maximum_grade) - Min(Minimum_grade)) > 2;
```

This selects teachers 3 and 4 which should not be the case.

**I assume this is because the code I wrote compares the minimum grade of course 4 with the maximum grade of the same course, which should not happen.**

I have no idea how to improve my code to obtain the desired results, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: teacher 4 does not match the last condition, why it should be selected?

Comment: Hi @Patrick do you need solution in Python ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest For teacher 4, the minimum grade of course 7 and the maximum grade of course 8 differ by 3, so it should be selected.

Comment: How much of this answer do you want in SQL and how much in python?  If this could be answered entirely in SQL is that ok? If this can be answered by using python to post process your initial query is that ok?

Comment: The reason your query is failing is because, it is checking for ```max_grade(X)-min_grade(X) > 2``` instead of  ```max_grade(X)-min_grade(Y) > 2``` as per your requirement.

Comment: @JonSG I just went through the requirements of the assignment again to check. It needs to be fully in SQL. Sorry for any confusion caused by my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this by selecting from your table twice, once with an eye to find the minimum grade and the second time to find the maximum. When we join those together we want to do so for teachers who share their id but making sure that the classes have different ids:

```sql
SELECT
    a.Teacher_ID,
    MAX(b.Maximum_grade - a.Minimum_grade) AS diff
FROM
    dataset as a JOIN
    dataset as b ON
    (
       a.Teacher_ID = b.Teacher_ID AND
       a.Course_ID != b.Course_ID
    )
GROUP BY
    a.Teacher_ID
HAVING
    MAX(b.Maximum_grade - a.Minimum_grade) > 2
```

You might try it here, though I don't know how long this sites keep these fiddles around: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c4a72/1

Comment: This solution looks cleaner than mine. I didn't think of making a self join.

Answer (score 2):

This query can still be optimised (or) converted into sub-queries. This is from the top my head. This consists of two parts, first we need to satisfy the  two conditions,

> 1. All teachers who taught 2 separate courses X and Y
> 2. Diff b/w the minimum grade of course X and maximum grade of course Y is greater than 2.

```
select teacher_id, max(max_g) as max_g, min(min_g) as min_g from dataset 
group by teacher_id 
having count(distinct course_id) >= 2 and (max(max_g)- min(min_g)) > 2
```

The above query fetches the records for the above condition, with just a little contradiction. The contradiction is, sometimes the difference b/w is calculated within the same course, ie

> max(max_grade of course X) - min(min_grade of course X)

To correct this, I'm just selecting records where max(max_grade) and min(min_grade) are from different rows( hence that courses will also be different).

```
with diff_gt_two as
(   
   select 
        teacher_id, 
        max(max_g) as max_g, min(min_g) as min_g 
   from dataset     
   group by teacher_id 
   having count(distinct course_id) >= 2 and 
   (max(max_g)- min(min_g)) > 2
)
select dataset.teacher_id from dataset,diff_gt_two
where 
     dataset.teacher_id = diff_gt_two.teacher_id 
     and 
     ( dataset.max_g = diff_gt_two.max_g or     dataset.min_g = 
       diff_gt_two.min_g) 
group by dataset.teacher_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Edit:
@JonSG has converted the CTE to subquery, fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c4a72/9
. Thanks JonSG

Comment: where does the column `dataset.max_g` come from?

Comment: Okay, the original table from the question is the one I named as```dataset```.

Comment: Ya, that table does not have a column named `max_g` :-)

Comment: Oh, I took the liberty to shorten ```maximum_grade``` to ```max_g``` and ```minimum_grade``` to ```min_g```.

Comment: Note: This solution also appears to work if one corrects for the shortened table names:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c4a72/9

Answer (score 1):

You can join the dataset with itself intersecting on same teacher with different courses and get the maximum differences per teacher from this cartesian product:

```
SELECT A.Teacher_ID, max(A.Maximum_grade-B.Minimum_grade) as Diff
FROM dataset A,dataset B 
WHERE A.Teacher_ID = B.teacher_ID and A.Course_ID <> B.Course_ID
GROUP BY A.Teacher_ID
HAVING Diff > 2;
```

*Because of the join's condition requiring different courses, teachers with only one course will not come out and differences of grades within the same course will be excluded*

Comment: Is this not essentially the same as my answer?

Comment: Yes!, apart from the syntax used, it is the same (I didn't notice that when I posted it)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Teacher_ID , max(diff) as DIFF, COUNT(Course_ID) as NUMBER_OF_COURSE
    FROM (
        SELECT *, (Maximum_grade  - Minimum_grade) AS diff
        FROM dataset
    )
    GROUP BY Teacher_ID
)
WHERE DIFF > 2
```

result = TEACHER_ID 3 , DIFF 3 , NUMBER_OF_COURSE 2

Comment: Would this solution not show the max differences between max and min grades of individual courses? If so, then it would select teacher 3 and not teacher 4 right?

Comment: as far as i have understood  the problem and comments  , i have done edit the code. thanks for contributions

Comment: This does produce the result you claim, but that is not the result the OP is asking for.  They do not want teacher 3 but rather teacher 4 as the result.

Answer (score 0):

**USING PYTHON**

DF:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'CID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8],
                   'TID': [1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4],
                   'Min': [7,5,5,5,6,5,4,5,6],
                   'Max': [8,6,7,8,7,6,6,7,7]})
```

Code:

```
ans = []   #Creating new list where we will store our result

#Creating new list with the teachers who attend two or more thn two courses
TID = [k for k, v in df.groupby(['TID'])['CID'].count().to_dict().items() if v>=2]



for T in TID:    #Loop Over Teachers

    #Lets just select the Min value row
    d = df.loc[df.loc[df['TID']==T][['Min']].idxmin().values[0]]

    #Lets add Max to row, while filtering just not select the Min CID here
    d['Max'] = max(df.loc[(df['TID']==T) & (df['CID']!=d['CID'])]['Max'].tolist())


    if(d['Max'] - d['Min']> 2):
         ans.append({T:  d['Max'] - d['Min']})
    
ans
```

Output:

```
[{4: 3}]  ### CID : DIff
```